# Save vector to file during debug session (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode

My application has crashed in an assert, and the debugger is attached. To be able to reproduce the crash I want to save a C++ vector with 397 struct{uint64_t, uint64_t} elements to file.

My first approach was to try to print the vector. I *can* print the vector to the console, but it seems like only the first 256 values are written. Is it possible to remove the 256 element restriction?

I've also searched for a way to save the vector to file from within the debugger, but I've not found any way. I've not even found a way to save a memory region, but I guess that *must* be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you're stopped in the debugger in Xcode, I'll assume you're debugging with `lldb`.  You can use the `expression` command to execute essentially arbitrary code when you're stopped in the debugger, for example:

```
expression for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { (void)NSLog(@"%d", j); }
```

Will execute a for loop and print the numbers 0 through 9.  You should be able to use a similar technique to iterate over your vector and write it to a file.  You can combine multiple expressions using a semicolon, just as if you were writing normal code (well, except for newlines).  For example, this will write "Hello, world" to a temporary file at `/tmp/vector.dat`, not exactly what you want, but I think you'll get the idea:

```
 expression FILE *fp = (FILE*)fopen("/tmp/vector.dat", "w"); (void)fprintf(fp, "Hello, world!\n"); (void)fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Awesome! I replaced NSLog with printf to write "{n1, n2}," lines ready to be pasted into a C code array assignment.